# What BigTIFF capable image viewers are there for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

I have looked at imview and evince but they do not seem to be able to open my BigTIFF files. Are there any viewers that can handle this file type?

Comment: Have you tried [feh](http://feh.finalrewind.org/), or [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)?

Comment: I got feh from the 14.04. repos: This is a BigTIFF file.  This format not supported by this version of libtiff..

Comment: Gimp also won't open my files.

Answer (score 1):

The very versatile [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) with the [BioFormats](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats5.0/users/imagej/) plugin will do the job. Using virtual stacks you can also display multipage BTFs with more pages than fit into your memory.

Comment: This seems like a little bit of an overkill to me if you just want a quick glance at the content of a file...